# Vuex store is undefined in NUXT middleware

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm practicing NUXT and from tutorial its working well. mine fail when entering the NUXT middleware. the logic is if page is redirecting to other page it will enter middleware and fetch the result using axios.

**middleware/search.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function ({ params, store }) {
    console.log(store)

    return axios.get(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=~${params.id}&entity=album`)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.results);
            store.commit('add', response.data.results)
        })
}
```

when entering here the `store.commit('add'...` will result

> Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined

when I echo commit = undefined.

What I'm missing? I already tried `this.$store.commit(...)` still undefined.

## VUEX

**store/index.js**

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      albums: []
    },
    mutations: {
      add (state, payload) {
        state.albums = payload
      }
    }
  })
}

export default createStore
```

Comment: thank you sir for correcting my question

Comment: no need yenmar in nuxt its already appended. restarting local server fixed the probl

Answer (score 18):

I found a solution from the comments of the said tutorial but I want to share here if others struggle it too.

halt your development server <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

then restart the your dev server

```
npm run dev
```

then VUEX will be seen now in the middleware tnx

Comment: It's doesn't seem the dev server rebuilds the vue store, this left me scratching my head for a couple of hours...smh

Answer (score 8):

Restarting the Dev Server worked for me as well. It seems Vuex isn't reloaded when changes are made.

Run `npm run dev` and it should work.