# How do load json data into the store from Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get the json file without a server.

[Vuex store is undefined in NUXT middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120277/vuex-store-is-undefined-in-nuxt-middleware)
I refer to this link and call it middleware.

json file failed to load and there was no error.
I have no idea what the problem is.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
 modules: ["@nuxtjs/axios"],
 axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
 },
```

**middleware/data.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

export default function({ params, store }) {
  return axios.get(require("~/data/character.json")).then(response => {
    store.commit("SET_CHARACTERS", response.data.results);
  });
}
```

**store/index.js**

```
export const mutations = {
    SET_CHARACTERS: (state, payload) => {
      state.character = payload;
    },
}
```

Restarting dev server is not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try importing the JSON file directly in your middleware, without using axios:

```js
import characters from '~/data/character.json';

export default function({ params, store }) {
   store.commit("SET_CHARACTERS", characters`);
}
```